# disable default Django models and migrations

Tags: django, django-admin

I created a Django project which is supposed to be a small service and it has nothing to do with User and other Django default models. How can I remove them completely? (I need Django admin)
When I comment `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALEDD_APPS` I recieve this error:

> RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Just don't use them. Alternatively, Django is potentially the wrong choice for this app if you don't want the included features. Perhaps think about something like Flask or FastAPI instead?

Comment: How do you want to differentiate between an admin and a "normal" app user without a `User` model? That is not possible. You are probably aiming for using the `User` model to authenticate your few admins and then keep all your "normal" users assigned to [`AnonymousUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser) which they are by django default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify here. Django includes a `user` with all requests. This may well be an anonymous user if nobody is logged in, but it's there. Trying to disentangle this is almost certainly not worth it.

Either:

a. Leave the user/auth stuff there and simply don't use it, which means the `is_authenticated` method will always return `False`.

b. Pick a different framework, or at least think carefully about what you want from a framework. Why have you picked Django for this when you don't want the features of Django in the first place?

Comment: Thank you very much. I used Django in my microservice and User is created in another service. So I just don't use User model simply.

Comment: I mean, you can probably remove it, but at the same time, it's not doing any harm and the likely hood of it slowing anything down is pretty minimal. Commenting the auth app and middleware may get rid of it (if you reinitialise your db and rerun migrations), but that might also cause issues with other middelware, I'm not sure.